how to covert a frame (np array) to a pytorch tensor
i need to convert a frame of the video (which is a nparray) to a pytorch tensor, do some particular actions with it and convert it back but i'm struggling
so, i have a frame returned from video_capture.read() and, as i understood, it's a np array. firstly, i convert it to a tensor and checks if looks correctly (sorry i can't add photos for some reason)
then i analyze it (no mistakes), try to rotate it and here's a problem.

frame.show() shows the tensor in different colours, looks super wrong
self.check_tensor(rotated_tensor) after rotation shows just a black screen

can somebody please help me to fix this, i'm so exhausted, chatgpt confuses me even more and don't understand anything... i guess the problem with colours is related to how i convert tensor to pil image, but i tried several changes (commented lines) and nothing hepled.
also is there a way to avoid converting tensor to pil image before the rotation? can't i just rotate a tensor?
def tensor_to_image(tensor):
    tensor = (tensor * 255).byte()
    tensor = tensor.squeeze(0)
    tensor = tensor.permute(1, 2, 0)
    image = Image.fromarray(np.array(tensor).astype(np.uint8))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image))
    return image

def rotate_tensor(frame_tensor, landmarks):
    roll = calc_face_angle(landmarks)
    frame = tf.to_pil_image(frame_tensor.squeeze(0))
    #frame = tensor_to_image(frame_tensor)
    frame.show()

    if not np.isnan(roll):
        rotated_frame = frame.rotate(roll, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
    else:
        print("Failed to calculate face angle for rotation")
        return frame_tensor

    #rotated_tensor = tf.to_tensor(rotated_frame).unsqueeze(0)
    
    transform = transforms.ToTensor() # Используем torchvision для преобразования в тензор
    rotated_tensor = transform(rotated_frame).unsqueeze(0)
    return rotated_tensor
    

def check_tensor(self, frame_tensor):
    frame_numpy = frame_tensor.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0).byte().numpy()
    #frame_numpy = cv2.cvtColor(frame_numpy, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame_numpy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)   
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


def analyze_video(self, video_path):
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    for i in range(1):
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        # преобразуем фрейм в тензор
        frame_tensor = torch.from_numpy(frame).float()
        frame_tensor = frame_tensor.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
        #frame_tensor = frame_tensor[:, [2, 1, 0], :, :]

        self.check_tensor(frame_tensor)

  
        orig_prediction = self.analyze_frame(frame_tensor)
   
        rotated_tensor = im.rotate_tensor(frame_tensor, orig_prediction.head())
        self.check_tensor(rotated_tensor)


This is how you can do it:
def frame_to_tensor(frame):
    # OpenCV frame (BGR) -> RGB tensor
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # Convert to tensor and add batch dimension
    tensor = torch.from_numpy(frame_rgb).float().permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
    # Normalize to [0, 1]
    tensor = tensor / 255.0
    return tensor

def tensor_to_frame(tensor):
    # Remove batch dimension and move channels last
    frame = tensor.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0)
    # Scale back to [0, 255]
    frame = (frame * 255).byte().numpy()
    # Convert RGB to BGR for OpenCV
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return frame

def rotate_tensor(tensor, angle):
    # Convert to PIL (expects RGB tensor in [0, 1])
    image = tf.to_pil_image(tensor.squeeze(0))
    # Rotate image
    rotated = image.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
    # Back to tensor
    return tf.to_tensor(rotated).unsqueeze(0)

# Usage in your analyze_video:
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
frame_tensor = frame_to_tensor(frame)
# Do your analysis...
rotated_tensor = rotate_tensor(frame_tensor, angle)
# Display/save
output_frame = tensor_to_frame(rotated_tensor)
cv2.imshow("Frame", output_frame)


Key point:

Always handle color space conversion (BGR ↔ RGB) when moving between
OpenCV and PyTorch Keep tensor values normalized (0-1) during
processing Scale back to 0-255 only for display/saving Maintain
consistent channel ordering (HWC vs CHW)



The reason frame.show() is showing the wrong colors is because OpenCV uses the BGR format while PyTorch and PIL use the RGB format. Your frame is created from OpenCV (BGR format) and then you attempt to display it with PIL (RGB format) without any conversion.
Usually for image processing, libraries expect values in the range [0, 1] for floats and [0, 255] for integers. The reason self.check_tensor(rotated_tensor) shows a black screen is because the image-to-tensor conversion in rotate_tensor() normalizes the values to the range [0, 1] and when you cast it to an integer in check_tensor() it floors all of the values to 0 since they are all decimals between 0 and 1 so you need to multiply the tensor by 255 after rotating.
Since your array already has a range [0, 255] you don't want to multiply it by 255 again in tensor_to_image() and if you do OpenCV and PIL will usually mod the values leading to unexpected colors.

def tensor_to_image(tensor):
    tensor = tensor.byte()
    tensor = tensor.squeeze(0)
    tensor = tensor.permute(1, 2, 0)
    image = Image.fromarray(np.array(tensor).astype(np.uint8))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image))
    return image

def rotate_tensor(frame_tensor, landmarks):
    roll = calc_face_angle(landmarks)
    frame = tensor_to_image(frame_tensor)
    frame.show()

    if not np.isnan(roll):
        rotated_frame = frame.rotate(roll, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
    else:
        print("Failed to calculate face angle for rotation")
        return frame_tensor
    
    rotated_frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(rotated_frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    transform = transforms.ToTensor()
    rotated_tensor = transform(rotated_frame).unsqueeze(0)
    return rotated_tensor * 255


What is the use of np.isnan here?
